# Error when using associate within an OpenMP loop in a Fortran code

Tags: fortran, openmp, associate

I have the following MWE:

```
  program main
  implicit none
  integer i,ints(5)
  ints(:)=0
  call omp_set_num_threads(5)
  !$omp parallel do default(shared) private(ints,i)
  do i=1,5
     associate(ii=>ints(i))
        write(*,*) ii
     end associate
  end do
  !$omp end parallel do
  end
```

whose expected output would be five zeros. However, this code prints random numbers when compiling with `ifort version 2021.7.1.`. My question would be how to resolve this conflict between `OpenMP` and `associate`?

Based on suggestions found on https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/OpenMP-with-associate-define-private/m-p/1180441, I tried the following two modifications:

```
  program main
  implicit none
  integer i,ints(5)
  ints(:)=0
  call omp_set_num_threads(5)
  !$omp parallel do default(shared) private(ints,i)
  do i=1,5
     block
     associate(ii=>ints(i))
        write(*,*) ii
     end associate
     end block
  end do
  !$omp end parallel do
  end
```

and

```
  program main
  implicit none
  integer i,ints(5)
  integer,pointer :: ii
  call omp_set_num_threads(5)
  ints(:)=0
  !$omp parallel do default(shared) private(ints,i,ii)
  do i=1,5
     associate(ii=>ints(i))
        write(*,*) ii
     end associate
  end do
  !$omp end parallel do
  end
```

but both of them print random numbers.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? What did the other tries produce?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Compiler: ifort version 2021.7.1. The other code variants also provide random numbers.

Comment: Please add the details by editing your question.

Comment: @PierU Done. Done. Done.

Comment: `ints` being private, it gets undefined once in the OpenMP region. You have to declare either shared or firstprivate.

Comment: @PierU Yes, you are completely right. Thanks. Then this is not a good example for my original problem.

Comment: In that case please make a different example. You can either rewrite the current question or delete this one and open a new question or we can close this one likely as a duplicate or caused by type and then you can open a new one.

Comment: Just to mention, in the past I have had bad experiences with ASSOCIATE and OpenMP , and I find the OpenMP specification quite unclear on that topic. I tend now to avoid ASSOCIATE names in OpenMP regions.

Comment: I agree, there were certainly bugs (even internal compiler errors)around for this in gfortran. The developers at the time pointed out that the OpenMP specification does explicitly specify what should happen.

Comment: @PierU and Thanks for your comments. You may have some advice to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581702/how-to-pass-subarrays-to-gemv-blas95.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581702/how-to-pass-subarrays-to-gemv-blas95. Any suggestions are really welcome.